# Swift/Xcode Buildtime warnings for gRPC-Core and gRPC-C++ after installing Firebase Pods

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I have recently installed Firebase using Pods to my project. While everything works fine with my app functionally, I am observing multiple Buildtime warning messages for gPRC-Core and gRPC-C++. See screenshot below. It is the same error message for every warning which states:

> Anonymous non-C-compatible type given name for linkage purposes by typedef declaration; add a tag name here

I have updated my cocoapods to the latest version and all my pods for Firebase are also up-to-date.

**Will this cause any problems for me in the future? Is there any way of getting rid of these warnings because more than anything else, it is annoying to see warnings in my project which i can't clear?**

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated. Cheers!

[image: Screenshot of Buildtime warnings from Xcode]

Comment: Unfortunately there's nothing we can do about those. They won't cause any problems. At one point these Firebase frameworks were giving off hundreds of warnings. It's up to those people to fix them.

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks for your input Tadreik.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't like seeing these third-party library warnings in my Xcode. I usually keep my build clean and so whenever some warnings or errors pop up in that pane, I know these warnings/errors are real and should be fixed before I push the PR.

Anyway, you can get rid of these warnings by simply adding this line in your `Podfile` and doing `pod install` again with this new config

```
inhibit_all_warnings!
```

This should remove all these annoying warnings and give you a clean project to work with. Cheers!